# Java jframe disposing issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

Well I have certain buttons on one frame when they are clicked they change colour. I have a "X" button at the top that disposes the frame. When i try to reopen the frame it opens, but when I click these buttons to change the colour, they're being clicked twice?

I dont understand why this is happening, I know its clicking twice because if clicked twice it goes back to black the original colour. Also, I added a System.out.println to determine how many times it was performed, and its printing it out twice on one click.

Does anyone know what is happening? And if so, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bug in code not shown -- please show your code.

I'm guessing now, but likely you're adding your ActionListeners multiple times to your JButton. Write your code so that the ActionListener gets written to the button once, say on class creation in the constructor, and not within some other listener. For better help, please show pertinent code.

Comment: It works fine the first time, it only goes wrong after disposing the frame and reopening, it is after that things don't perform as they should

Comment: @AcDSa: exactly -- because you're likely adding an action listener with the first call perhaps within the same ActionListener itself. But again, **why make us guess**? Please show your pertinent code. **Seriously**

Comment: Sorry its part of a GUI and theres a lot of code, what part of the code shall I paste?

Comment: @AcDSa: the code that's causing your error. You've got to do some debugging and some thinking on this. You want to write your code so that it is easy to isolate and test individual small sections of the project. Doing this reduces "cyclomatic complexity" and makes debugging and enhancing **much** easier to do.

Comment: Close frame button (action performed) = dispose();
open frame button =  seatChooser sc = new seatChooser();
        sc.setVisible(true);

Comment: @AcDSa: Please [edit your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29398221/edit) and post any and all code in there. Post more code than that -- any code that calls addActionListener to the key JButtons and the surrounding code. Your code is too important to be buried in a comment.

Comment: I've just understood what you've said, the problem was each time I was clicking on the button to reload it was instantiating the other class.